# update trigger on inserting row in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am newbie to sqlite and I am trying to use triggers for first time this is my first job... and I  have two tables VData and listed  where both have  same column called vrm and points, I am inserting an new row into data table and i want to update this column vpoints from the listed table npoints  if there is same reference of vrm on both tables. but after trigger it has the old value and not the new one from listed table. thanks

My triggers are here 
Insert vrm

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Insert vrm]
    AFTER INSERT
    ON [VData]
    BEGIN 

        UPDATE VData
        SET vPoints = (SELECT nPoints
                                     FROM listed
                                     WHERE VRM = NEW.VRM)
        WHERE Id = NEW.Id;
    END
```

updatevrm

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UPDATE vrm]
AFTER UPDATE
ON [VData]
BEGIN
UPDATE VData 
SET vPoints = (SELECT nPoints
                                 FROM Listed
                                 WHERE VRM = NEW.vrm )
                                 WHERE  Id = NEW.Id;

END
```

Comment: I am now having an doubt that is this query really difficult to sort out

Comment: These triggers look correct. Create an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5).